# Is there a difference between branch and trunk transactions?

Tags: transaction, branch, trunk

I understand that a transaction confirms two other transactions (*branch* + *trunk*).

Is there a special semantic or rule for *branch* and *trunk* or are this just two words chosen to denote the two referenced transactions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For most purposes (e.g. determining confirmation status or propagation of transactions) it does not matter which transaction is where.

Inside a bundle, however, it is at some places clearly mandated which transaction has to be the `trunk` transaction and the `branch` transaction (e.g. when signatures are split between multiple transactions, they have to be chained via the `trunk` transaction and not the `branch` transaction). This restriction makes it faster for nodes to validate transactions and bundles for formal correctness.